# Php is there a way to turn a string into function args?

Tags: php

Is there a way in php to turn a string like `'2,3'` into a form that can be used for function parameters with a function like `function addition($foo,$bar){ return $foo + $bar; }`

Comment: `explode()` your string into an array and use `call_user_func_array()` with it

Comment: Perfect, That's just what I'm looking for.